# in `require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, httparty

My default ruby is 2.0.0p384.

A ruby script has:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
```

If the above header is changed to:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
```

the script runs fine.

`/var/lib/gems/2.0.0/gems/httparty-0.13.5` exists.

I can't understand why running the script with the 2.0.0 ruby gives:

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- httparty (LoadError) from usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in`require' from ./check_pingdom:30:in `'

Comment: the gem is installed for 1.9.1 but not for 2.0.0.
are you using rbevn or rvm or doing everything by hand?

Comment: Hi Mircea. It is all manual. I want to have the least impact and footprint on the production system.

Comment: the gem is installed for 1.9.1 but not for 2.0.0. try running "gem env" to see where it is attempting to pick up the gems.

Comment: gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
:

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?